# Can you mix ASP.Net and Unobtrusive JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Is it possible to mix the concept of Unobtrusive JavaScript with the event model of ASP.Net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET makes it very difficult, as every server side control requires a postback via the `__doPostback` javascript function.

You can make sure you are not using any server side controls, but this means you loose most of the benefits of ASP.NET.

Another option is to override the `OnRender` event and output different controls/javascript, but this is also quite a lot of work and defeats the purpose of ASP.NET.

You have much greater control when using ASP.NET-MVC.

Answer (score 0):

yes, to a point. discounting standard controls and how they are built, there's not much stopping your from offloading all your own javascript to a separate file. the big hangup that comes to mind is referencing `myControl.ClientID` to render an element id in the middle of a script block. with a little planning, you can still minimize the amount of script you have to render in the page to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this question has already been answered but for anybody surfing in, I somewhat disagree with the accepted answer.

It depends on what controls you are using.

Not all the controls require JavaScript.  The biggest culprit for me was always LinkButton.  A regular button control does not use JavaScript at all however.  On my pages, I actually use regular buttons and use CSS and JavaScript to make them into LinkButtons.  The first step is to use CSS to make them look like links.  If you really want to get fancy, you can detach the button, add an HTML anchor, and associate all the event handlers for the button with the anchor.  This means that a user without JavaScript sees a regular button (HTML input) that is styled with CSS.  Anybody using JavaScript will see an HTML link (

Also, if you use JQuery, it is very easy to select ASP.NET elements without worrying about all the extra mumbo-jumbo that ASP.NET adds to the IDs.

Example:

```
<asp:Button id='theButton' text='Click here' cssclass='linkbutton' runat='server' />
```

You can select this individual button using JQuery:

```
var theButton = $("input[name$='theButton']");
```

You can also replace everything of class 'linkbutton' with HTML anchors:

```
$(function() {
    var buttons = $(".linkbutton");
    buttons.each(function() {
        var button = $(this);
        var id = button.attr('id');
        /*
         * If a link button is not working
         * it is likely because it does not
         * have an ID attribute - check that
         */
        if (id)
        {
            var text = button.attr('value');
            var cssclass = button.attr('class');
            button
                .before("<a id='"+id+"' class='"+cssclass+"' href=''>"+text+"</a>")
                .hide()
                .detach();
            $("a[id='"+id+"']").live('click', function(event) {
                $(this).after(button);
                button.click();
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Things like GridViews are a bit more work but also doable.  I found that, after the initial honeymoon, I avoided those kinds of controls and just used repeaters anyway.  Repeaters do not impose any nasty JavaScript either.

Anyway, it is certainly possible to do unobtrusive JavaScript with ASP.NET WebForms.